# Excel: Count how many times a value appears in a row

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, constants

Below in the pic on the right side you have got the values. On the left the excel formula "count(And(A4=A5);1;0)" is included which counts how many times each value appears in a row. You see the value "2" and "8" appears twice in a row. The formule is however cumbersome. A more practical way would be to have a formula over the column which counts all values that are constant once in a row then twice in a row etc. Would be the "index" command a solution?

[image]

Comment: do you have access to **TEXTJOIN** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A4:A15=A5:A16))
```

And

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A4:A15=A5:A16)*(A4:A15=A6:A17))
```

Notice that all the ranges have the same number of cells, just offset.

[image]

Comment: A good answer but I think the OP is after a more universal solution that can count the values that occurred consecutively as many times as needed.

Comment: Scott is right. The values can appear as many times as needed and also the length of the columns with values can vary. In my example the value "2" appears 3 times consecutively but only once. The value "8" appears once consecutively and also only one time. And my aim is to have a formula that counts and answeres the questions: How many times have the values been constant one consecutively times.How many times have the values been constant twice consecutive times.How many times have the values been constant three consecutive times and so on.

Comment: @YavuzTopal I have wracked my brain, and the only thing I can come up with to make it dynamic is vba.  A formula just will not do the looping you require.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you very much for your effort. good to know.VBA would be a solution which I am going to implement then. THank you all